# reading variable in unix shell script and performing operation

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk

I need to read a variable in shell script and using that variable to perform some operation. For e.g. I am reading variable markets from config and using this variable to find out the value of another variable `redis_host_silver_$j`

command used :-

```
for j in `echo $markets | awk -F"," '{ for(i=1; i<=NF; ++i) print $i }'`;
do
    echo $(redis_host_silver_$j);
done
```

Can anyone help me in this?

Comment: im getting error like below :-  + for j in '`echo $markets | awk -F"," '\''{ for(i=1; i<=NF; ++i) print $i }'\''`'
++ redis_host_silver_uk
test.sh: line 61: redis_host_silver_uk: command not found

Comment: Try quoting around your echo, like `echo "redis_host_silver_$j";`

Comment: Also if you have the permissions to do so, it would be helpful to edit the original question to add error message

Comment: `eval` might be needed... You probably want arrays though... Also `$(stuff)` will run `stuff` and replace in the result. (`a=1;$(stuff_$a)` will run `stuff_1`)

Answer (score 1):

The error is in the `echo $(redis_host_silver_$j);` part.

The `$()` syntax in bash expands what's inside as a command so you're actually trying to execute `redis_host_silver_$j`

Try:

```
for j in `echo $markets | awk -F"," '{ for(i=1; i<=NF; ++i) print $i }'`;
do
    echo "redis_host_silver_$j";
done
```

---

If `redis_host_silver_...` is a name of a variable that you want the value of then do this:

```
for j in `echo $markets | awk -F"," '{ for(i=1; i<=NF; ++i) print $i }'`;
do
    VAR=redis_host_silver_$j; echo ${!VAR};
done
```

Note the curly brackets

Comment: Glad to help. Which method did you use?

Comment: Indirect expansion seems like a much better option than `eval`... (Which is how I would have approached it...)

Answer (score 0):

I personally would steer away from using a for loop to read data directly from process substitution which may or may not have white spaces in it.
And whilst the indirect call may work, I would say that your variable type is wrong and the second variable, redis_host_silver, should actually be an array with the items from the file as indices.

So maybe something like:

```
IFS="," read -ra items <<<"$markets"

for item in "${items[@]}"
do
    echo "${redis_host_silver[$item]}"
done
```

If the values from "markets" are numbers, then "item" variable in call to array does not require "$"